# executing multiple SQLite SELECT queries in Java Swing netbeans

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, netbeans, jframe

I have a java Swing Application that in which i'm designing a small brain challenge game. The issue is that I'm stack at the first stage of the game where I want to load the details of the current user from an sqlite database, but from two different tables. Here's my full code:

```
//This is the method that loads the data
private void showDetails(){
    try(Connection dbConn = dbConnect.initConn()){
        Statement stmt = dbConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM status");

    //Display the name of the Current User 
    if(rs.next()){
        currentUserLbl.setText(rs.getString("currentUser"));
   else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An Unknown Error Occureds.");
       dispose();

       indexMenu im = new indexMenu();
       im.setVisible(true);
   }
   stmt.close();

   //Update the form with the other values from the database
   PreparedStatement uStmt = dbConn.prepareStatement("SELECT Score, Level FROM users WHERE Name = ?");

            uStmt.setString(1, currentUserLbl.getText());
            ResultSet uRs = uStmt.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                levelLbl.setText(rs.getString("Level"));
                highscoreValue.setText(rs.getString("Score"));
            } 
            else{
                //This error shows up anytime I run the code
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An Unknown Error Occured.");
                //This line also seems not to work
                this.dispose();

                indexMenu im = new indexMenu();
                im.setVisible(true);
            }
            uStmt.close();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }        
}
```

Anytime I run the program, it shows the error I've indicated in the code. I just don't know what I've done wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to use: `if(uRs.next()){                levelLbl.setText(uRs.getString("Level"));
                highscoreValue.setText(uRs.getString("Score"));
            } `. ;)

Comment: Well, changing it didn't seem to work. See it here: http://soundboxgh.000webhostapp.com/GameError.png

Comment: In you **catch** block make **e** return the error and display it within the JOptionPane, for example: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());` Let us know what that exception truly is. Better yet, comment the JOptionPane code line and place `e.printStackTrace();` under it within the **catch** code block. Display the stackTrace within your post.